# Ohms law applications

Tags: voltage, current, resistance

As you change the value of resistance of the resistor,how does this change the current through the circuit and the battery voltage?

Comment: Physics describes what happens, not how or why. And I don't see how changing the resistance changes the battery voltage (unless you are thinking of a non-ideal battery).

Answer (score 2):

Ohm's law answers this question.

$$I = V/R$$
The only extra idea needed is to assume the battery voltage (V) doesn't change. This is an 'ideal' battery, it is reasonable unless the resistor value is quite small (see below).

reducing the value of R (resistance, measured in Ohms)
increases the value of I (current, measured in Amps)

increasing the value of R
decreases the value of I

Crucially, changing the value of the resistor *does not change the battery voltage* (unless the resistor is small, see below). This seems to be a common source of confusion.

When the value of the resistor is quite small, then you will need to worry about the battery. The battery will be 'stressed', and no longer have 'ideal' behaviour. The batteries voltage may fall, it may get hot (changing its performance), and it may quickly become 'flat' (unable to supply current).

Further, the resistor might no longer be 'ideal', it might heat up enough for its value to change too.

Ohm's law will still apply, but it is harder to make reasonable assumptions to calculate the current.

Edit:
The definition of a 'small resistor' depends on the batteries capacity and chemistry. For example, school physics may use resistors above 20 Ohms with a 1.5 Volt D cell. This might be 'ideal enough' for simple Ohms Law experiments in the classroom. For something like a hearing-aid battery, with a 100mAH capacity, the resistor might need to be several hundred Ohms to allow the battery to approach the 'ideal'.